# Set background to be full width and height

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
body {
  background: url("https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/mountain_lake_landscape_trees_79396_2560x1600.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/rts05xt2/

I want that the image to be full width and full height, and if someone resizes the browser, the image will not resize again, just stay like that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `background-size:initial`?

Comment: Yes, you can try and see that it not resize the image, and show maybe 30% of the image... @jhamon

Comment: @Web R your code seems working...

Comment: The image isn't in the maximum height... @PrajwalShrestha

Comment: Do you using bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, I am @ChoncholMahmud

Comment: well, with `initial` it gets its full width and full height and it's not resized when the browser is. In my opinion, that seems to fit what you ask in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the below CSS :

```
body {background:url("https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/mountain_lake_landscape_trees_79396_2560x1600.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; background-size : cover}
```

Comment: Thanks, its works but one thing - When I resize the browser and minimize the browser for example, the image is resize too, and I don't want it. How I can avoid it?

Comment: Cover will resize or adjust its width accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html { 
  background: url(images/ho.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This is the perfect way

Comment: Do you support Fx 3.6, Opera 10.1 and Android 2.3?

Comment: I dont understand YOUR question

Comment: I'd have been more clear with a link to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts), sorry. The 3 prefixed properties are only useful for ooooold versions of browsers.